# Manifestresource stream load gives null reference expection on some files

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm doing a Xamarin project and having this problem and I don't know how to fix it.

I'm trying to get some data from a `.txt` file. I've already fixed it and it works on one of the files, but when I switch to another file it suddenly gives me `NullReferenceException`.

Here's the code that works:

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(ReadFromTxtFile)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("HanafiSalahTider.salahtider2019.txt");

using (StreamReader myreader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    fileContent = myreader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Here's the nonworking code:

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(ReadFromTxtFile)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("HanafiSalahTider.salahtider.txt");

using (StreamReader myreader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    fileContent = myreader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Here's both files in the solution explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be able to load a manifest resource, the *Build Action* of that file needs to be set to *Embedded Resource*. To check this, select the file, right click on it a select *Properties*. In the properties window, change the *Build Action* to *Embedded Resource*.